# Shell Script to Display Number of Files and Directories in a Directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, find

I'm trying to write a script that will tell you how many files and how many directories are in a given directory.

Here's the script I've written, but the output is always "Number of files is ." and "Number of directories is ."

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -d "$@" ]
then
find "$@" -type f | ls -l "$@" | wc -l | echo "Number of files is $@"
find "$@" -type d | ls -l "$@" | wc -l | echo "Number of directories is $@"
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be confused on piping here.

You want the output of `find ... | wc -l` to be expanded in the `echo` command.

So, your script, given what you want to accomplish should look something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d "$@" ]; then
    echo "Number of files is $(find "$@" -type f | wc -l)"
    echo "Number of directories is $(find "$@" -type d | wc -l)"
else
    echo "[ERROR]  Please provide a directory."
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: thanks this worked! I need to find a different textbook on shell scripts. This Unix Power Tools one isn't enough.

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be having difficulties to understand how pipes work. You cannot "natively" use the "result" (stdout) of a pipe (the left-hand side) as a variable on the right-hand side of a pipe, you either need to consume and read it into a variable, e.g.

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" | while read line; do_stuff_with "${line}"; done
```

or you need to use command substitution (and optionally assign it to a variable), e.g.

```
files=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf . | wc -c)
```

A few further notes:

- `$@` expands to all positional parameters, in case of multiple arguments your `[ -d "$@" ]` will fail.
- The `ls` is completely superfluous
- `find` works recursively, but I guess you only want the first directory level to be checked so this needs the `maxdepth` parameter
- This will break on weird paths with newlines which can be worked around by telling `find` to print a character for each found directory/file and then count bytes instead of lines

In case you really don't want this to be recursive it might be easier to just use *globbing* to obtain the desired result:

```
$ cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

for file in "${1-.}"/*; do
        [ -d "${file}" ] && ((directories++))
        [ -f "${file}" ] && ((files++))
done

echo "Number of files: ${files-0}"
echo "Number of directories: ${directories-0}"
```

.

```
$ ./t.sh
Number of files: 6
Number of directories: 1

$ ./t.sh /tmp
Number of files: 9
Number of directories: 3
```

You might want to check `man test` to tweak with regards to links to obtain your desired result.

Comment: Fruwrith, thank you! there's a lot of great info here. I haven't learned most of it. I'm going to use this as a starting off point for doing more research. Thank you again