# Bash Scripting - Display number of files and folders in a directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to bash scripting, and I found this [example on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472417/shell-script-to-display-number-of-files-and-directories-in-a-directory). Now, it seems this is what I need however, I'm unsure of a few things.

1. How would I properly modify it to display the number of files and folders in the downloads directory
2. What does the "$@" mean?

My code so far:

```
cleanPath="/home/someuser/Downloads/*"

if [ -d $cleanPath]; then
    find "$cleanPath" -type f | ls -l $cleanPath | wc -l | echo "Number of files is $@"
    find "$cleanPath" -type d | ls -l $cleanPath | wc -l | echo "Number of directorieis $@"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, but you have some syntax errors (spaces needed around if statement brackets) and some other mistakes. `cleanPath="/home/someuser/Downloads/*"` can cause problems if you don't properly quote cleanPath like `"$cleanPath"` because the shell expands *, so you actually get a list of all files and directories in Downloads (try `echo $cleanPath` and you will see). Also, I don't see why you pass the output of find to ls, ls will not even use the input, it will just list all the files and directories.

Try this:

```
cleanPath="/home/someuser/Downloads"

if [ -d "$cleanPath" ]; then
  echo "No of files is ""$(find "$cleanPath" -mindepth 1 -type f | wc -l)"
  echo "No of directories is ""$(find "$cleanPath" -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l)"
fi
```

Be aware this is recursive - default `find` behaviour. You didn't make it clear whether that was what you wanted. For a non recursive list:

```
cleanPath="/home/someuser/Downloads"

if [ -d "$cleanPath" ]; then
  echo "No of files is ""$(find "$cleanPath" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)"
  echo "No of directories is ""$(find "$cleanPath" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | wc -l)"
fi
```

Also you can use `$@` as an array representation of all the positional parameters passed to a script.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_0024_0040

Beware: -mindepth -maxdepth are not POSIX compliant, and this doesn't work for files with newlines.

Comment: It works, BUT, it says that they're 2 directories in Downloads, when in fact it is only 1 directory. What is this?

Comment: The first one is recursive. Also I fixed a mistake. I guess you want the second example

Comment: Perfect, the second one is what I want. One more questions, and sorry I didn't mention it before, is it possible to capture the results in variables for example the number of files in one variable and the number of directories in another?

Comment: @CharlesWhitfield pass it to the variable, i.e. `VAR=$(...)`. `VAR` must start at the beginning of the line, and no space before and after `=`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf No it's not wrong, not on my OS. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Did I ever say it was POSIX? Look at the tags - linux, bash. Neither are POSIX. If all answers here were limited to POSIX they would be very limited indeed

Comment: OK if you quote the variable then it doesn't expand the `*`, point taken. And most OSs based on the linux kernel use GNU Tools. And linux isn't even POSIX compliant itself. Bash definitely isn't POSIX compliant

Comment: And with regards to the newline - that's just nitpicking to the point where it's ridiculous - even `ls` doesn't display newlines in files properly, nautilus will show a funny square in the filename in the bottom right hand corner when you select the file. No one does it, and if they do they should expect problems anyway - why waste time talking about every rare corner case?

Comment: If you want a cool method to count the files and directories with just one `find` traversal: `a=$(find "$cleanPath" -mindepth 1 -type d -printf d -o -type f -printf f); nbfiles=${a//[^f]} nbfiles=${#nbfiles} nbdirs=${a//[^d]} nbdirs=${#nbdirs}; echo "${nbfiles} files and ${nbdirs} dirs"`. This will work with files containing newlines _and_ will be more efficient.

Comment: In fact even bash autocompletion doesn't work on files with newlines

Comment: About files containing newlines: if your method only works 99.99999% of the time, it's broken. Moreover, you're lying if you don't specifically mention the weaknesses of your method. It's that simple. The way you edited your answer makes it really good now (and it wasn't that difficult, was it?)—except for those ugly `""` that should be removed—and you deserve my `+1`.